# Why do you have to cast a bitwise operation on a byte to a byte in Java?

Tags: java

Why is the cast necessary here?

```
byte a = 0b0000_0000;
byte b = (byte) ~a;
```

`a` is a byte, `b` is a byte... why do you need to cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.5) says so

> Unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1) is performed on the operand. The type
>   of the unary bitwise complement expression is the promoted type of the
>   operand.

[and](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1)

> Otherwise, if the operand is of compile-time type `byte`, `short`, or
>   `char`, it is promoted to a value of type `int` by a widening primitive
>   conversion (§5.1.2).

A value of type `int` is not assignable to a variable of type `byte`.

Comment: What a weird rule. I'll accept the answer in ~11110101 minutes when I can.